Program crashes after EOF is sent
I am building a basic command line interpreter, to support 4 commands, a command can be entered entirely in one line, such as
wc -w "Hello World!" 
and that would output 2, as this is the word count command, and that all works well, however, my commands can be entered by typing only the command name (and option if it exists) and then pressing enter to enter the argument in a new row, such as:
echo
Hello World!
this way after the first enter is pressed i need to take inputs (arguments) , until a line is EOF. Generally this is similar to how a real command line would work im pretty sure. The error occurs exactly in this case, when the argument is entered this way, after EOF is pressed, it does the function it should the way it should, but automatically calls the next command (because the program should work in an infinite loop), which is blank and therefore crashes the program. These are some of my functions
string Reader::readLine() {
    cin.clear();
    char line[maxLineLength];
    cin.getline(line, maxLineLength);
    return line;
}

Command* Parser::parseLine(const string& line) {
    stringstream ss(line);
    string word;
    string words[3] = {"", "", ""};
    size_t pos = line.find('"');
    int hasQuote = 0;
    if (pos != string::npos) {
        hasQuote = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (ss >> word) {
            words[i] = word;
        }
        else {
            words[i] = "";
        }
    }
    string function = words[0];
    string opt, arg;
    if (words[1].front() == '-' && !hasQuote) {
        opt = words[1];
        arg = words[2];
    }
    else if (words[1].front() == '"') {
        opt = "";
        arg = line.substr(pos, line.length());
    }
    else if (words[1].front() == '-' && hasQuote) {
        opt = words[1];
        arg = line.substr(pos, line.length());
    }
    else {
        opt = "";
        arg = words[1];
    }
    Command *res = nullptr;
    if (function == "echo") {
        if (arg.empty()) {
            arg.clear();
            string tmp;
            while (getline(cin, tmp)){
                arg += tmp + "\n";
            }

            cin.clear();
            arg = "\"" + arg;
            arg[arg.length() - 1] = '\"';
        }

        res = new EchoCommand(arg);
    }
    else if (function == "date") {
        res = new DateCommand();
    }
    else if (function == "time") {
        res = new TimeCommand();
    }
    else if (function == "touch") {
        res = new TouchCommand(arg);
    }
    else if (function == "wc") {
        res = new WcCommand(arg, opt);
    }
    else {
        cout << words[0] << " is not a valid command." << endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    return res;
}

void Runner::run() {
    while (true) {
        cout << c << ' ';
        string line = reader->readLine();
        Command *command = parser->parseLine(line);
        command->execute();
        delete command;
    }
}

bool EchoCommand::execute() {
    string arg = getArg();
    if (arg.front() == '"') {
        cout << arg.substr(1, arg.length() - 2) << endl;
    }
    else {
        ifstream file(arg);
        if (!file.is_open()) {
            cerr << "File not found" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main(){
    Runner *runner = Runner::getInstance();
    runner->run();

    return 0;
}

I have heard that calling cin.clear() should solve this, but it doesnt for me, i have put it into the parseLine function, i have tried other places as well, nothing works, when debugging at the breaking point, in the run() function it says that line = "", and command = NULL. Which i dont understand why, because i dont enter anything like i should be able to, it just calls the next loop for the next command, and instead of asking me to input a new command it reads an input which i havent entered and reads line = "". Help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

My guess is the EOF (however you entered that) has killed the terminal. Using cin.clear() will tell your program to ignore an EOF error, but it doesn't resurrect a terminal that has been killed. The terminal is a different program, not something that is under your control. But I'm only guessing.

EOF cannot be "pressed", EOF is an end of file or error indicator. What OS? If you have sent EOT (End of Transmission character) in terminal, stdin descriptor is closed, std::cin cannot read from it anymore and indicates EOF. Why do you use std::cin.getline() with C-style array rather than std::getline(std::cin, ...) which can create std::string?

On macos, by pressing ctrl + D, i send EOF to the stdin. I need the program to then do the command and move on to request another.

A [mre] should be posted. Minimal means all unrelated code should be removed. Reproducible means other users can run and debug your code.

@MoneyLuke After pressing Ctrl+D stdin is closed, you can't read it anymore. Expected behaviour for a program which reads stdin and got EOF usually is termination. If you want to handle EOT in another way, you have to configure tty line discipline in platform-specific way, on macos probably the same as on other *nix'es, by tcgetattr/tcsetattr. Lines (commands) are usually separated by \n.

"I am building a basic command line interpreter" -- That's nice, but hardly relevant. For this question, reduce your program to a basic "read EOF then fail to read the next line" program. Don't give us the parsing code; if your analysis is accurate, all you need is to read the line after EOF and output whether or not that line is empty (no crash necessary). Don't even bother having input before EOF unless that is required to reproduce the error.
